# Edit with javascript a remote shared excel file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel

I created a web app with react Js. My goal is to create a form that when completed add the data to an existing excel file that is shared online. I need to edit rows too if I'm changing data of an existing row.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

E.g.: I have a form with 3 inputs: name, surname and address. When I complete the form and press send, I want that these info are added in a new row of a shared online excel file.

Comment: Using the ExcelJS library might help. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74849678/changing-existing-excel-spreadsheet-in-react